# Web Api - Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-web-api

In the last few years, I have seen the rise of many Web APIs - services exposed over plain HTTP rather than through a more formal service contract (like SOAP or WS*). Microsoft has just launched a new framework called "ASP.NET Web API" hat makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of clients. Event if I am a .net fan, it is another communication framework (after asmx, wcf, ria, ...). Now, working as an happy architect, I have to take decision over technologies.

Is Asp.net Web Api really a good choice for a new architecture? Remember Linq2Sql, I do not want to invest in a "disposable" api.

Is there still a use for WebBindings in WCF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with this question, in terms of it being a stack overflow question, is that it's basically subjective. As a result, I'm pretty sure it'll be closed - but I'm going to stick my 2 pence (it's more like £2 actually) anyway and if it gets closed so be it.

First Linq2Sql isn't 'disposable' - it's still there and not going to go away. It's not being *developed* - that's another matter entirely.

Anyway - The Asp.Net Web API is a formalization of REST web service support by many people from the same team that work(ed) on Asp.Net MVC and uses a very similar approach to extensibility, pipelining, cross-cutting concerns (e.g. authentication, logging, validation) and such.  Whether you use it or not is entirely down to whether you are intending to develop RESTful web services.  If you are, and you're on .Net 4+, then, in my opinion, you'd be mad not to.

The overall architecture in the Web API is very good and you can extend most of it without too much effort at all.  In particular, the way that they have handled content negotiation is very very nice, making it trivial to, for example, support JSON requests but returning XML responses just because a client sends `Content-Type:application/json` and `Accepts:application/xml`.

As a server technology it's also very very fast; partly because it's entirely asynchronous (increasing scalability) but also because the stack between a request coming in, to your code being called, is very shallow.

Not only that but you can host it in both IIS and in any .Net application also - which increases your hosting options but also makes it a candidate for intra-network communications within a common network (i.e. non-internet) environment.

If, however, you want to write a SOAP or WS-HTTP service then, no, the Web API is not for you - you'd stick with WCF.

In short - you need to think of the Asp.Net Web API purely as a server and client technology running on .Net as opposed to a protocol or web architecture.  It enables you to build RESTful web services - you can also do that in MVC, WebForms (if you really wanted to), .ashx handlers, or by writing your own HttpListener.

Which of those you choose is entirely up to you to decide.

Comment: Linq2Sql : it's just an example of how MS can invest many ressources in a technology and then focus on something else. you're true, that's another matter.

Comment: Web API is a HTTP stack.  It provides a basis on which someone could build a REST framework, but it has no opinions on the architectural style.  Technically, the client stack is not part of web api, it's part of the .net framework and built by a different team.

Comment: Good point on the fact that the client stuff is not part of the stack, but actually further underneath it - have removed (I'd never used these shared types before till working with the Web API).

Comment: @ All : i have read tutorials and a great part of the documentation. I understand how it works and i have already experience in Rest Approach. I think is it easy and a great API. My question is more "Do you feel the same ?" @ Andras Zoltan : obviously it is subjective. As i said, i want some feeback and  others point of view because selecting this framework will impact my dev team for the next 2 or 3 years.

Comment: @Cybermaxs I've gone all the way down the rabbit hole with a new REST layer for my organisation using the Web API and it's brilliant.  And because of it's similarity to MVC I've been able to merge both environments (our own custom DI container, configuration etc) seamlessly as well; with WCF it was nowhere near as easy. Web API is also open source so it's much easier to find those much needed extensibility points when you need to.

Answer (score -1):

We can call ASP.NET Web API a replacer of WCF Web API.
It will support more platform oriented service.

Comment: It actually evolved from WCF Web Api and was moved into ASP.NET when most (possibly all) of the team that worked on WCF WEb Api merged/moved to the ASP.NET team.

Comment: I don't believe it is intended as a replacement.